# Monitoring interfaces and subscribing to multicast on them

Tags: linux, sockets

How can a program enumerate the available IP interfaces, and monitor changes in them, to subscribe to and send IP multicasts on all of them?

I ask because I am troubleshooting a problem with the mediatomb server which appears to want to run `route add -net 239.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 eth0` and `ifconfig eth0 allmulti` ( and these commands require that you know the interface in question and that it already be configured ) before it can successfully start.  I am pretty sure that if the program were coded correctly, it should be able to subscribe to the required multicast group on every available interface and send out on them, but I'm not quite clear how.  I have read [this](http://www.tenouk.com/Module41c.html) and it explains how to bind to a multicast group on an interface if you know its IP address, but not how to find all IP addresses on the system, and keep up with any changes.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Umm.. so that the program can operate properly without having to be manually configured and tied to a specific interface?  You know, plug and play.

Comment: Does the interface have some sort of discovery mechanism?  It's going to take awhile to probe all those IP addresses, and some devices will view it as an intrusion attempt.  There are 255⁴ possible IP addresses, and we haven't even touched on ports yet.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I'm not talking about probing *other hosts* on the network.. I'm talking about being notified when you plug in the cable and get a DHCP address for yourself.  i.e. how do you discover all of your *own* machine's addresses?  ala `ifconfig -a`.

Comment: [Here's the source for ifconfig](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/sbin/ifconfig/ifconfig.c?rev=1.169&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup).  Maybe that will help.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I don't think it will since `ifconfig` is a one time run.  What I am looking for is a way to ask the kernel "tell me when a new IP address is configured on an interface".  For that matter, why the *hell* do you even have to do this with multicast?  Broadcasts to 255.255.255.255 simply go out on all up interfaces, even ones that come up long after your program starts.  Why does linux require that you explicitly bind to a specific interface to send multicast?  That just seems wrong.  Multicast *should* go out over all interfaces just like broadcasts.